# How to implement complex arrays?

Tags: javascript

For example, when `id` is equal to 1, an array is `['a', 'b']`, and when `id` is equal to 2, another array is `['c']`. The result of these two arrays is `[["a","b "],["c"]]`

**I want the results as follows:**

```
[["a","b"],["c"]]
```

**my code:**

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'c'
  }
]
```

Comment: `var data = [["a","b"],["c"]]`

Comment: iterate the elements, create an array element at position `id -1` and push each `name` that corresponds to that index (with the caveat that if you're missing indexes it'll be a somewhat pathological array). What's the specific issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'c'
  }
]
let result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return item.id === 1 ? acc[0].push(item.name) : acc[1].push(item.name), acc
  
},[[], []])

console.log(result)
```